# Pygame assiging to rect.attributes doesn't change the anything

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

From the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

"Assigning to size, width or height changes the dimensions of the rectangle". 
I have the following circle, assign a new attribute but no changes can be seen in circle. What am i doing wrong?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

TV=pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rect")

c=pygame.draw.circle(TV,(0,100,0),(150,150),100,1)
pygame.draw.rect(TV,(100,0,0),c,1)
print c.size
c.size=(100,100)
print c.size
pygame.display.flip()

while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You draw the circle on the screen surface. Every drawing function then returns a `Rect`, [but](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle):

> The functions return a rectangle representing the bounding area of changed pixels.

To actually change the circle on the screen, you have to erase it first (draw something above it), then draw a new circle in the size you want.

Here's a simple example:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Rect")

TV = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
c = pygame.draw.circle(TV, (0, 100, 0), TV.get_rect().center, 100, 1)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 250)
value = 10
run = True
while run:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            run = False
        if e.type == USEREVENT:
            c.inflate_ip(value, value)
            if c.width > 260 or c.width < 200:
                value *= -1

    TV.fill(pygame.color.Color('Black'))
    pygame.draw.circle(TV, (0, 100, 0), c.center, c.width/2, 1)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```